# How to show Word Header and Footer in Web layout view?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016, headers, footers

In Word 2013 or Word 2016, how does one view the header and footer in the Web layout view? I see it in the Print layout view. That's no problem.

But no such luck in the Web layout view? Was the Web layout view not designed to show the header and footer?

I've tried adjusting the top margins to push down the header but it's not as if the header is not even rendering in the Web layout view.

Comment: Is it even sensible to have a "header" or "footer" on a web page?

Comment: Headers and footers are defined as specific areas at the top and bottom of a printed page.  Their content, like page numbering, is tied to pages of a certain paper size.  They don't translate to web pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web layout view, like the Draft view, are not designed to display Headers and Footers. While you are in one of those views, if you use the Header button on the Insert tab of Word to edit the Header content, the view is automatically switched to the Print Layout view.